# Inner filtering of array doesn't filter swift

Tags: swift, filter

I am trying to filter an array of structs that has array. Below are the data structures I am using. I want the inner array filtered also but it doesn't work

```
var objects = [SomeObject]()      //array of objects
var filteredObject = [SomeObject]()  //filtered array
var isSearching = false

struct SomeObject {
    var sectionName: String
    var sectionObjects : [History]
}

struct History {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: Int
}

func searchBar(_ text: String) {
    filteredObject = objects.filter({ (obj: SomeObject) -> Bool in
        return obj.sectionObjects.filter { $0.firstName.contains(text.lowercased())}.isEmpty
    })
    print("====", filteredObject, "fill===")
}


let history = History(firstName: "John", lastName: 1)
let anotherHistroy = History(firstName: "Dee", lastName: 2)
let historyArray = [history, anotherHistroy]

let newObject = SomeObject(sectionName: "Section 1", sectionObjects: historyArray)

objects.append(newObject)
searchBar("Jo") // printing of filtered object should not have another history in it's sectionObjects
```

Comment: What is the _desired_ output in your example, and why?

Comment: `==== [test.SomeObject(sectionName: "Section 1", sectionObjects: [test.History(firstName: "John", lastName: 1), test.History(firstName: "Doe", lastName: 2)])] fill===` which is the content of `objects` and that means the second filter isn't working. If `sectionObjects` contains the searchText it returns the whole struct instead of filtering it

Comment: But none of them contain “Jn”. So why should anything be filtered out?

Comment: `history`'s `firstname` `John` contains Jn

Comment: I don't see where it contains that. It has a `J` and it has an `n`, but it has no `Jn`. Could the problem be that you don't know what `contains` means? Try printing out the result of `"John".contains("Jn")`. You will see that it is false. It doesn't contain it (in any sense known to Swift, or to me for that matter).

Comment: When I do `Jo` the filtering does not work either

Comment: Fine, now you've got a viable question.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
func searchBar(_ text: String) {
    filteredObject = []
    for var ob in objects {
        ob.sectionObjects = ob.sectionObjects.filter {
            $0.firstName.contains(text)
        }
        if !ob.sectionObjects.isEmpty {
            filteredObject.append(ob)
        }
    }
    print("====", filteredObject, "fill===")
}
```

Could perhaps be done more elegantly with `reduce(into:)`, but on the whole it is best to start simply by saying exactly what you mean. You can tweak as desired to take account of case sensitivity.